# apache SetEnvIf Request_URI getting 404 Not Found error

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

Currently running site on apache server on ubuntu and now whole site is protected with .htaccess authentication.

Want to do: I need to allow two URL without authentication.

sites1.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(tools|manager)/
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /srv/site1/symfony/>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "My Area"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile "/etc/apache2/passwords.htpwd"
    Require user user1

    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/en/App/uploadImagesForm allow
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from env=allow
    Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

URL: xxx.xxxx.xx:9005/en/App/uploadImagesForm/

Error:

> 404 Not Found
>   The requested URL /en/App/uploadImagesForm was not found on this server.